# Why 1D00FFFF and not 1CFFFFFF as target in genesis block

Tags: genesis-block, difficulty-retargetting

Is there a specific reason why 1D00FFFF is the target bit for the genesis block and not 1CFFFFFF? Both bits are forcing 8 zeros in the front of the hash (hexadecimal).

Regards steff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the custom uint256 encoding used in Bitcoin, bit 0x00800000 denotes the sign, so 0x1CFFFFFF actually denotes the value *-2<sup>200</sup>(2<sup>23</sup> - 1)*. Obviously the target value cannot go negative, so this aspect of the encoding is not useful in this context, but for whatever reason, that's what Bitcoin's creator chose.

Comment: Thank you that was helpful. I am not so deep in coding. That means when I am looking at the last 6 digits 000000 to 7FFFFF are positive and 800000 to FFFFFF are negative?

Comment: @steff123 That's right.