# Recalculating the target and truncating

Tags: difficulty-retargetting

The target on the block at height **32,255** was:

```
0x00000000ffff0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

After the adjustment, the target on the following block at height **32,256** was:

```
0x00000000d86a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

The time between block **30,240** and block **30,255** was `1022578` seconds. If we divide this by the expected time over 2016 blocks we get a ratio of:

```
1022578 / 1209600 = 0.84538525132275
```

If we multiply the previous target by this ratio to get the new target, we get:

```
0x00000000ffff0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 * 0.84538525132275 =
0x00000000d86a528bc8bc90000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

What are the rules for truncating this result to get the target as stored the in the block header?

I understand that the target is converted to bits and loses some precision, but why is it that we're only including the first two significant bytes of `d86a` when we could include the three bytes of `d86a52` in the bits field?

Answer (score 2):

When encoding from target to bits, in the custom uint8 encoding used in bitcoin, bit `0x00800000` denotes the sign.

So any value greater than `0x7fffff` would actually be considered a negative number.

Therefore, `0x00d86a` must be used when encoding the target to bits instead of `0xd86a52`.

---

Pieter Wuille's answer here: [Why 1D00FFFF and not 1CFFFFFF as target in genesis block](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/113535/why-1d00ffff-and-not-1cffffff-as-target-in-genesis-block)

I believe the actual code itself can be found in the `GetCompact()` method  in https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/arith_uint256.cpp